# does checking for nullptr 100% protect from segfault regarding memory layout?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, nullptr, memory-layout

Lets say I am iterating over an array, but go beyond this array because my loop is stupid.
If an object in memory is located directly after this array of the same type as this array, can
checking `array[invalid_index] == nullptr`
protect me?

What is the correct way to check whether an index (size is not known) is valid for a C array?

Comment: *can checking array[invalid_index] == nullptr protect me?* -- No.

Comment: It cannot. There's no guarantee that array[x] where x is out of bounds is even readable.

Comment: why do you think `nullptr` helps? 0% is much closer to the truth...

Comment: No. The correct way to check if an index is valid for a C array is to calculate the size or track the size and compare the index to that.

Comment: Use `std::array` and `std::array::at`.

Comment: There are only 2 ways to know when to stop iterating, know the size/have an end iterator, or use a sentinel value.

Comment: Don't use C-style arrays *at all*. Use `std::array` and/or `std::vector`, both of which *know* their `.size()`.

Comment: you can also get the size of a C-style array with `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)`

Comment: The act of accessing the value of `array[invalid_index]` is what causes undefined behaviour - with a potential symptom of a crash.    (A crash is NOT guaranteed to occur when behaviour is undefined - a crash is only one possibility of many).   And all that happens BEFORE comparing with `nullptr` since the operands of `==` are evaluated before they are compared.

Comment: @Tscheppe Not after it has decayed to a pointer. For example after being passed to a function. And besides, using `std::size()` is a better alternative to that `sizeof` and division thing...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible to determine the size of an array through a pointer to it's first element. You need to communicate the size somehow.

Common strategies are to keep your array as an array and communicate the size through the type system, provide the size as a separate value or use a sentinel value (like a null character in a c string). In c++, it's recommended to use `std::vector` or `std::array` which always know their own size.

Trying to dereference an array element beyond the bounds of that array is undefined behavior. As soon as you try to read `array[invalid_index]` you have undefined behavior. So it's not possible to use `array[invalid_index]` for any useful purpose, including bounds checking. `nullptr` has no effect here at all.

Answer (score 6):

No, checking for `nullptr` does not protect you. At all. 0%.

It was you who created the array in question. The correct way to check whether an index is valid is to know what size of an array you created (which you do; remember: it was *you* who created the array) and then check whether the index is within range. Even better, write code such that indices don't go out of range in the first place and, thus, no checking is required to begin with…

With exception of the hypothetical element after the last element of an array, the attempt alone to even just *compute* (not even access, just compute) the address of an element that is not part of the array immediately invokes undefined behavior [[expr.add]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.add#4). And, without exception, attempting to access an element that is not actually an element of an array always invokes undefined behavior no matter what. 100%. The built-in subscript operator is just shorthand for computing the address of the given element and accessing the object at that address [[expr.sub]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.sub#1). Thus, you actually don't even get to a point where you *could* compare the value you read to `nullptr` before you enter undefined behavior land…

Answer (score 2):

This sort of check won't protect you.

Many C APIs have a sort of contract with the programmers using it that they'll obey the conventions specified by the API without any kind of strict mechanical enforcement of that contract. For example, C-based String APIs mostly assert that strings are always null-terminated, and that correct use of any C-based string API will assume and depend on a string being null-terminated.

When this contract is in place, it's *generally considered to be safe* to perform these kinds of checks, because the person passing you the string is supposed to guarantee this contract, usually by padding the string or data structure with an extra null value specifically and explicitly for fulfilling this contract, like this:

```
char string[13] = "Hello World!"; //string[12] contains the value 0

/*...*/
char const* str = string;

do {
    char curr = *str++;
    if(curr == 0) 
        break;
    /*...*/
} while(true);
```

In most C-based String APIs, that code is considered "safe" within the specific context of that contract being guaranteed.

But this depends on the programmer behaving themselves, and that cannot be guaranteed. It wouldn't take much for a programmer to misbehave with their code and something like this:

```
char string[12] = "Hello World"; 
string[11] = '!';
```

would immediately break the string loop I just showed. This is why C++ programmers feel (rightfully, in my opinion) that these kinds of checks are unsafe: they simply cannot be guaranteed correct unless you trust your users (programmers) to obey your rules.

This is why we prefer APIs that cannot unexpectedly break like this.

```
std::string string = "Hello World!";
for(char curr : string) { //for-each loop, intrinsically safe unless the iterators are improperly implemented
    /*Do whatever with curr*/
}
```

So to circle back to your original question: the safe way to handle this is to use the objects specifically designed to keep us safe. Use `std::array<T, N>` instead of `T arr[N]`, which will then allow use of for-each loops. If you need to use index-based iteration, prefer `at(index)` instead of `[index]` in any situation where performance is not at a premium. These are the kinds of practices that will make your code safe, instead of just trusting your data is properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

> does checking for nullptr 100% protect from segfault

No. There are many ways to access invalid memory, and null pointer is only one of them.

What you must do is avoid all undefined behaviour.

> What is the correct way to check whether an index (size is not known) is valid for a C array?

The way to check it is to compare with the size of the array:

```
if (index < size)
    // valid
```

If you don't know the size of the array, then you cannot check for the validity. Other typical sources of bugs are wrongly assumed size or lifetime of the array.